# How to compare?

Tags: usage

> Few Scientists changed people's ideas as much as Charles Darwin with his theory of evolution, yet as a boy he showed **little sign** of becoming a great scientist.

I think there is an error in the bold part because **sign** is a countable noun and **little(determiner)** is used for uncountable nouns.

But I found this sentence in a book, that is why I am confused.

Comment: It's true that we're much more likely to say [*he showed **no** sign of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+showed+little+sign+of%2Che+showed+no+sign+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20showed%20little%20sign%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20showed%20no%20sign%20of%3B%2Cc0) [whatever]*, rather than ***little** sign*....

Comment: ...but with [***no/little enthusiasm***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=showed+little+enthusiasm%2Cshowed+no+enthusiasm&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20enthusiasm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshowed%20no%20enthusiasm%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20enthusiasm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshowed%20no%20enthusiasm%3B%2Cc0) they're about equal. I doubt many native speakers worry about this one too much though.

Answer (score 1):

I can *almost* get my head around the idea that there might be something wrong with combining the determiner ***little*** with a countable noun such as ***sign***. But that's just an *idea*. The reality is what people say and write...

[(chart link)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show%20no%20sign%20of%20wear%2Cshow%20little%20sign%20of%20wear&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshow%20no%20sign%20of%20wear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20little%20sign%20of%20wear%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshow%20no%20sign%20of%20wear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20little%20sign%20of%20wear%3B%2Cc0)[image]

And [here's another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=showed%20little%20sign%20of%2Cshowed%20little%20signs%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20sign%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20signs%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20sign%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshowed%20little%20signs%20of%3B%2Cc0) showing that it doesn't make *that* much difference whether there's more than one ***sign*** now being shown...

[image]

---

TL;DR: There may be *logical* arguments against the usage, but in practice it's not something that bothers native speakers much.